# How to write logfile in csv format using logback?

Tags: java, csv, logback

I have a requirement where I need to write a log in a csv format using logback. I have found a sample where I can do just that

```
    <appender name="csv" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>mylog.csv</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <!-- rollover daily -->
    <fileNamePattern>mylog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.csv</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- each file should be at most 100MB, keep 60 days worth of history, but at most 20GB -->
        <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>    
        <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>20GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
       <encoder>
         <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
     </appender>
```

However I also need to have a standard header like this in every file:-

```
    Time,User,Param1,Param2
```

How do I add the header in every rolling file

Comment: To write a header line into every file you'll probably have to extend your appender class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement your own `Layout`, extending Logback's [`PatternLayout`](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/PatternLayout.java):

```
public class LogFileHeaderPatternLayout extends PatternLayout {

    private String header;

    public void setHeader(String header) {
        this.header = header;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFileHeader() {
        return header;
    }
}
```

And then reference it like so:

```
<encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
    <layout class="x.y.z.LogFileHeaderPatternLayout">
        <header>a,b,c,d</header>
        <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </layout>
</encoder>
```

If Logback insists on adding this header evey time it opens the log file (i.e. every time the application starts) then you could conditionalise `getFileHeader()` like so:

```
public String getFileHeader() {
    if (alreadyContainsHeader()) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return header;
    }
}

private boolean alreadyContainsHeader() {
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains(header)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is working correctly but the only problem is whenever I reboot the application the header gets appended once again. How do I ensure that it does not happen?

Comment: @KaushikChakraborty I have updated the answer to offer a solution to the 'multiple file headers' issue.

Comment: The 'alreadyContainsHeader'  check is quite involved, requiring opening a live file and reading its content (first line but still). Wouldn't a better solution be to only check if file exists and is not empty?

Comment: 'PatternLayout' is log4j's class, is it not?

Comment: There is a [`PatternLayout`](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/PatternLayout.java) in Logback too.

Comment: thanks. you got my upvote! but... where do u get 'filePath' from (in alreadyContainsHeader())

Comment: You'd have to inject that value into the custom layout class in the same way that `header` and `pattern` are injected e.g. `<filePath>...</filePath>`